# Using Random User generator to create profiles with angular.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I'm trying to get this done using the RUG (Random User Generator) API but I can't get this to work. I should be calling the http request after a click event but it doesn't seems to work. Here is what I've done (and sorry for my amateur code):

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="clk" style="background-color: indigo; widht: 100px; height: 100px"></div>

    {{"Hello world"}}
    <div ng-controller="firstController">
        {{ store.email}}
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('people', []);
app.controller('firsController', ["http",function (http) {

    var store = this;

    store.products = []; 


    $http.get('http://api.randomuser.me').success(function(data){
        store.products = data.results[0].user;
    })
}]);
```

OR

```
var boton = document.getElementById('clk');
boton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://api.randomuser.me/',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data.results[0].user);
      }
    });
});
```

Neither of this can work. Could I get this to work, to click a button and loading a new user from the api and use it with angular?

Comment: which error you are getting ? please explain that part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the **correct way** to use `$http` service and **scope variables**.

```
<html ng-app="people">
  <head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var app = angular.module('people', []);

        app.controller('firstController', ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {

          $scope.store = {};

          $scope.store.products = []; 


          $http.get('http://api.randomuser.me').success(function(data){
              $scope.user = data.results[0].user;
          })

        }]);
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="clk" style="background-color: indigo; widht: 100px; height: 100px"></div>
    <div ng-controller="firstController">
        {{ user.email}}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using `this` in a controller is not *always* wrong, especially when using `controller as myctrl` syntax in the HTML. Just as a generic warning, in this case it'll indeed help